# Export-Counter -Fileformat csv append?

Tags: powershell

I wanted to run get counter against a set of computers and output the value to a csv , i saw that Export-Counter does not have an append parameter?

Can some one help out on how to append a csv wiith more information using Export-Counter, i know export-csv has an append parameter but what if i want to append data to csv generated by Export-Counter.

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: why not use the `-circular` switch i think it is made for this ? see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849683.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you got 2 choices here. If you need it for a report to print, and save it with export-csv. Ex:

```
Get-Counter | select ...(if you want need to modify output)| Export-Csv -Append test2.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

If you need it to import later(need the real performancecountersampleset-object), try storing the previous in a array and add the new counters. Ex:

```
$path = "C:\test.csv"

#1st time
Get-Counter | Export-Counter $path -FileFormat csv

#Next time you use
$a = Import-Counter $path
$array = @($a)
$b = Get-Counter
$array += $b
$array | Export-Counter $path -FileFormat csv -Force
```